# Space sci-fi movie where a woman goes to space and loses her memory

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I've been to a couple of subreddits already trying to identify this movie, but I've had no luck besides one person who vaguely recognized the plot, but didn't know the name.

I watched a movie at some point in recent memory, most likely the last few months, but I don't actually know what time period the movie is from, although I suspect it's newer (2017-2019). I'm not sure what platform I watched the movie on, though my Netflix history doesn't show anything matching the description so far, and I can't get access to my PLEX viewing history (I'm not the admin).

Anyway, what I remember of the plot is this... there was a woman who had trained her whole life to be an astronaut, and was given command of a mission. She was in maybe her late 20s to early 30s and I believe had dark hair. However, once she and her crew reached orbit, she began to act confused and erratic, claiming to not know what was going on. It was revealed that she had a rare brain disorder that caused her to experience memory loss in space, and as a result, they had to abort the mission, and it destroyed her career.

I'm not entirely sure, but I believe she may have gotten pregnant afterwards, but ultimately I believe she ended up killing herself.

That was not all there was to the plot, as I believe this was only the first 10-20 minutes of the movie, but I cannot for the life of me remember the rest of the plot or what the name of the movie was. I've had my doubts about whether it was a movie, but I'm 99% sure that it was.

Some of the common suggestions were:

*Predestination*, however, this is not possible, as the reason for the main character's ejection from the space program wasn't because they had memory loss, but because

> it was a women's only program and she was discovered to be intersex.

*Brain on Fire*

> The main character's brain disorder had nothing to do with memory loss, and the movie had nothing to do with space or sci-fi.

Here is the /r/tipofmytongue post: [[TOMT][Movie] Sci-Fi Space Movie with Memory Loss](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/ddn0ce/tomtmovie_scifi_space_movie_with_memory_loss)

There have been no replies yet to my /r/scifi post, though.

Comment: I found the TV series "Pandora", does that ring a bell?

Comment: Maybe "Lucy in the Sky"?

Comment: @Markus The plot for that series (Pandora) doesn't match anything besides the main character being a woman.

Comment: @Markus Also, I have not seen Lucy in the Sky, and the plot for that movie does not involve memory loss.

Comment: It might be an episode of a series.  Maybe check the series you watched.  Especially those of stand alone episodes.

Comment: [Was the actress Indian perhaps?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlK1QzNTwgE)

Comment: @Walt No, I've never watched any Indian films. When I do watch foreign films, it's usually Japanese samurai movies or the rare artsy French / European film.

Comment: It's not an Indian film, it's American. The actress just happens to be Indian and I just thought you might recognize her from the trailer I linked above. It's called [One Under The Sun (2017)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5110386/) and the plot is kinda what you were looking for (black-haired female astronaut comes back from a space mission with memory issues).

Comment: @Walt Ah, I must have missed that. Either way, the trailer doesn't ring any bells and from what I've been able to find of the movie plot, it doesn't match up. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 3):

I only managed to get through the first couple of episodes, but this sounds like the Netflix/Amazon Prime series [Extant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extant_(TV_series)) staring Halle Berry.

> Molly Woods, an astronaut with ISEA (International Space Exploration Agency) is assigned a 13-month solo mission aboard space station Seraphim. She returns home to her husband John, a robotics engineer who created their son Ethan, a prototype android called a "humanich". When Molly discovers that she has mysteriously become pregnant despite years of infertility, she begins a search for answers.

While memory loss isn't explicitly mentioned in the premise, obviously being pregnant and not knowing why suggests some sort of memory problem.

By episode 3 it's shown that her young son is a robot (she knows), in case that helps place the show for you.

The [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3155320/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1) links may jog your memory.

[image: I'm struggling to find an iconic image.]

Halle Berry obviously has dark hair. Marketing for the show and the fact it was a box set full release dump may have made it feel like a movie to some viewers, particularly if they didn't stick it out to the end.

Comment: I can say for sure that this isn't it, as the memory loss upon entering space is the thing I remember clearly about the movie, and it was not a solo mission. Also, there were no robots involved. The name doesn't ring any bells either. I'm interested in this though, so I may check it out.